# How to force .NET DLL to load version 6 of comctl32.dll

Tags: c#, dll, manifest

I've got an Outlook addin DLL which uses the TaskDialog within the WindowsAPICodePack. Unfortunately after trying to show the dialog i get following error: "TaskDialog feature needs to load version 6 of comctl32.dll but a different version is current loaded in memory". I found out that it is possible to force an assembly to load version 6 by adding following to the manifest:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

That only works for executables. Within a library i do not have the option to link the project with a manifest file.

Is there any other possibility to archieve the wanted behaviour?

Comment: Winforms does this, Application.EnableVisualStyles().  You want to [copy the pinvoke](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,b70decd46dd26cf2) that's necessary for this.